# Sort posts in category list by title and number {wordpress}

Tags: wordpress, title, numeric, posts, alphabetical-sort

So i'm trying to list my posts in a specific category by title, but when i do that, the code returns:

- Post 2
- Post 11
- Post 10
- Post 1

i already tried everything that i found on web, without luck. :\

Actually i'm using the old way of retrieve posts which is

```
global $query_string;
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=1000&order=DESC&orderby=title' );
```

The expected result is:

- Post 11
- Post 10
- Post 2
- Post 1

Thanks in advance!